Querying user group memberships using GraphAPI SDK fails
I am in the process of upgrading the various dependencies of an app I have which queries an GraphAPI fetching some users details. I am upgrading from version 5.x of the GraphAPI version to 6.5.x (latest) and it seems that querying for group memberships does not work properly (seems to work in 5.x).
My code is the following:
    public List<Group> fetchGroupMemberships(String userId) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
            log.warn("Cannot fetch group memberships for null user or a user with an empty/null id...");
            return List.of();
        }
        var groupMemberPage = client.users()
                .byUserId(userId)
                .memberOf()
                .get();

        var fetched = new ArrayList<Group>();
        while (groupMemberPage != null) {
            var groups = groupMemberPage.getValue() != null ? groupMemberPage.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(object -> object instanceof Group)
                    .map(object -> (Group) object)
                    .toList() : null;
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(groups)) {
                log.debug("Appending groups {} to existing list...", groups);
                fetched.addAll(groups);
            }
            var odataNext = groupMemberPage.getOdataNextLink();
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(odataNext)) {
                log.debug("No more groups to fetch. Breaking...");
                break;
            } else {
                log.debug("Fetching next page of groups...");
                groupMemberPage = client.users()
                        .byUserId(userId)
                        .withUrl(odataNext)
                        .memberOf()
                        .get();
            }
        }
        return fetched;
    }

As you can see, I pass in an userId and use it simply to query the memberships of said user. However when I do so the following exception occurs:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array: {"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.group","id":"<uuid-of-group>","deletedDateTime":null,"classification":null,"createdDateTime":null,"creationOptions":[],"description":null,"displayName":null,"expirationDateTime":null,"groupTypes":[],"isAssignableToRole":null,"mail":null,"mailEnabled":null,"mailNickname":null,"membershipRule":null,"membershipRuleProcessingState":null,"onPremisesDomainName":null,"onPremisesLastSyncDateTime":null,"onPremisesNetBiosName":null,"onPremisesSamAccountName":null,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,"onPremisesSyncEnabled":null,"preferredDataLocation":null,"preferredLanguage":null,"proxyAddresses":[],"renewedDateTime":null,"resourceBehaviorOptions":[],"resourceProvisioningOptions":[],"securityEnabled":null,"securityIdentifier":null,"theme":null,"uniqueName":null,"visibility":null,"onPremisesProvisioningErrors":[],"serviceProvisioningErrors":[]}
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:117)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.iterateOnArray(JsonParseNode.java:167)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getUntypedValue(JsonParseNode.java:245)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.tryGetAnything(JsonParseNode.java:317)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.assignFieldValues(JsonParseNode.java:299)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getObjectValue(JsonParseNode.java:213)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.lambda$getCollectionOfObjectValues$1(JsonParseNode.java:195)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.iterateOnArray(JsonParseNode.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getCollectionOfObjectValues(JsonParseNode.java:195)
    at com.microsoft.graph.models.DirectoryObjectCollectionResponse.lambda$getFieldDeserializers$0(DirectoryObjectCollectionResponse.java:34)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.assignFieldValues(JsonParseNode.java:297)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getObjectValue(JsonParseNode.java:213)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.send(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:296)
    at com.microsoft.graph.users.item.memberof.MemberOfRequestBuilder.get(MemberOfRequestBuilder.java:110)
    at com.microsoft.graph.users.item.memberof.MemberOfRequestBuilder.get(MemberOfRequestBuilder.java:96)

From what I can get, it seems that the client is not able to parse the JSON response but I am not able to understand why this is the case. I am using the approach mentioned in the official documentation found here.
I can simply roll back to the latest version that I know works (5.x) but I would like to understand the problem that I am facing. For reference I think it might be related to this but I am not 100% sure.
Any help would be appreciated!

It's related to this: https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-java/issues/1147

Version 6.6.0 of microsoft-graph with azure-identity in 1.12.0 has the problem fixed.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-beta</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0</version>
</dependency>

